# how to add extra label at zero levels in x-axis in chartjs

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

[image: chartjs library]

As mentioned in above image, 2017 label should come at 0 levels on x-axis at both sides. I can send that 2017 and 2017 as extra labels

Answer (score 1):

Handled this through adding extra elements to the list and through css margin.
Working now